# Typescript generic function to return a string, number, or boolean

Tags: typescript

I have a function in Typescript and I want the return type to be determined by the type of the value found in the function when it reads from process.env.

For example, the global variables in my Node process.env can be string, number, or boolean (in my case). I would like to retrieve them as their specific types and have no warnings/errors at compile time.

My compile time errors are all similar to below, just with variations on string, number, and boolean. I highlight in the function where I see these errors.

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.ts(2322)
```

I am getting compile time errors in this simple function below. Any idea how I can return these values generically?

```
function get<T>(envVar: string): T {
  // Not actually getting the value from process.env for this example.
  
  // If the process env value is a string, return a string.
  if (envVar === 's') {
      return 'string value';
      // compile error here: 2322
      // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  }
  
  if (envVar === 'n') {
      return 52;
      // compile error here: 2322
      // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  }
  
  if (envVar === 'b') {
      return true;
      // compile error here: 2322
      // Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  }

  return null;
}
```

Calling code:

```
// No compile errors. This is how I expect to use this function.
const s1: string = this.get<string>("s");
const n1: number = this.get<number>("n");
const b1: boolean = this.get<boolean>("b");

// Another way, no compile errors. I am not defining a type, so why is this working?
const s2: string = this.get("s");
const n2: number = this.get("n");
const b2: boolean = this.get("b");

// Compile errors below, which is expected.

// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts (2322)
const sN: string = this.get<number>("s");

// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts (2322)
const nS: number = this.get<string>("n");
```

Here is a pseudo-code example of what I would like to do, but I am not sure if it is possible in Typescript.

```
function get<T>(envVar: string): T {
  // Get variable value from process.env, the value will always be a string 

  const val; // just assume val exists as a string

  // Based on what T is, we want to return the right type 
  if (T instanceof Number) {
    return Number.parseInt(val) as T; // return as number
  }
  else if (T instancef Boolean) {
    return Boolean.parse(val) as T; // return as boolean
  }
  else {
    return val as T; // return as string
  }
}

// calling code:
const s1 = get<string>("key");
const n1 = get<number>("key");
const b1 = get<boolean>("key");
```

The more I think about it, my real problem is, can I infer what type "T" is when it is passed in and trigger off of that to do something to return an object of type "T?"

And the more I think about that, the more I think, maybe I should just do this.

```
const s1 = get("key");
const n1 = getAsInt("key");
const b1 = getAsBoolean("key");
```

Comment: I suppose TS is inferring an actual generic type from a variable where a result will be stored

Comment: Using overloads would probably be better here.

Comment: None of `s1` through `b2` are really "working", in each case you are just asserting a type on top of `unknown` which can be essentially anything. I agree that overloads are probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a crucial piece of information that you seem to be missing is that in typescript, all type information available at compile time is erased.
That means any kind of expression like `T instanceof Number` can never work. `T` is not a value, but a type, and after compiling, it just wouldn't be there any more, which is why the typescript compiler would refuse to compile it.

If you want the behavior of your function to change, depending on typing information, you have to pass that information in form of something that isn't just a type, but also a value.

Something already mentioned in the comments to your question is the concept of overloads. These are indeed a good way to solve the problem you're facing.
For instance, you could have a second argument that allows passing an optional type identifier.
This can then be used within the code of the function to change the output type.
By writing multiple type definitions for the function, typescript will be able to realize the output types depending on the input types you give to the function.
When using your `get` function as an example, this is how it could look like:

```js
function get(envVar: string): string;
function get(envVar: string, toType: "number"): number;
function get(envVar: string, toType: "boolean"): boolean;
function get(envVar: string, toType?: "number" | "boolean") {
  const val = "Example value" as string;
  if (toType === "number") {
    return Number.parseInt(val); 
  }
  else if (toType === "boolean") {
    return Boolean(val); // return as boolean
  }
  else {
    return val; // return as string
  }
}
```

As you can see, this doesn't work via generics any more, but over multiple function signatures instead.
This also gives you the certainty that from within the function you actually return a suitable type, since typescript will otherwise complain that the "overload signature is not compatible with it's implementation"

Comment: Thanks for your input on this. I will move forward with the overload approach. The generic functionality I was looking for in Typescript just doesn't exist. Even if it did though, I don't know that it would really benefit me much.

If this were to work: const n1 = get<number>("key");
That's really no different than: const n1 = get("key", "number");

Thanks for the help.